# Why does my code make ID null

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a program that gets values from a database through a stored procedure. What it does is gets the values, downloads an image and then uploads it to a server. and after upload the run another stored procedure just to update the table to the new url.

Now it uploads a few images correct then all of a sudden it makes my ID = "" and I cant see why?

Result as log file:

```
Property ID : 29140
pk_photo_id (TRY): 47334070
 - File : propimage29140_9.jpg has been uploaded to AWS S3 bucket: ruans

Property ID : 30402
pk_photo_id (TRY): 47174447

Property ID : 29330
Property ID :              `<-- why make it nothing`
pk_photo_id (TRY): 47174392
ERROR 6 : Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ET_EXPORT_PROPERTY_QUEUE' with unique index 'idx_pk'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>).
The statement has been terminated.
```

My VB sub where this takes place:

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath)

            'for each image get file name 
            For Each images As String In files
                Dim id As String = ""
                Dim photoID As String = ""
                Dim position As String = ""
                For Each str As String In IDS

                    If Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey).Contains(str) Then
                        id = str
                    End If
                    Log("Property ID" & id)
                    For Each value As String In PhotoIDS
                        photoID = value

                    Next
                    For Each URL As String In fullURL
                        fullURLIndex = URL
                    Next
                Next
                'AWS upload
                Try
                    utility.Upload(txtFolderPath & sKey, bucket)
                Catch
                    needsToExitSub = True
                    Dim cmdSetError As New SqlCommand("ETSP_UPDATE_PHOTO_URLS")
                    cmdSetError.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmdSetError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stype", "L")
                    cmdSetError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surl", fullURLIndex)
                    cmdSetError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", 3)
                    cmdSetError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_photo_id", photoID)
                    Log("pk_photo_id (CATCH): " & photoID)
                    cmdSetError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bactive", 1)
                    cmdSetError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property_id", id)
                    cmdSetError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", clientIDs)
                    conn.Open()
                    cmdSetError.Connection = conn
                    cmdSetError.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Log(" - ERROR 4 : File : " & sKey & " Image ID : " & photoID & " Has NOT been uploaded to " & bucket & " , URL: " & fullURLIndex)
                    conn.Close()
                    If needsToExitSub = True Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End Try

                'Make files public - check this
                Dim cannedACL As S3CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                Dim fileNameOnly As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey)
                Dim token As String = fileNameOnly.Remove(fileNameOnly.LastIndexOf("_"c))
                Dim number As New String(token.SkipWhile(AddressOf [Char].IsLetter).ToArray())

                'Run stored procudure and update if uploaded
                Dim cmdSet As New SqlCommand("ETSP_UPDATE_PHOTO_URLS")
                cmdSet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stype", "L")
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surl", Convert.ToString("www.url.com/" & bucket & "/" & sKey))
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", 2)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_photo_id", photoID)
                Log("pk_photo_id (TRY): " & photoID)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bactive", 1)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property_id", id)
                cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", clientIDs)
                conn.Open()
                cmdSet.Connection = conn
                cmdSet.ExecuteNonQuery()

                conn.Close()
            Next
            Log(" - File : " & sKey & " has been uploaded to AWS S3 bucket: " & bucket)
        Catch ex As System.NullReferenceException
            Log("ERROR 5 : " & ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("ERROR 6 : " & ex.Message)
            Exit Try
        End Try
```

So the images downloads file to my computer in the correct folder, then it uploads it also to the correct folder but then when it comes to update the database to update new url and the other parameters it gives the error, now i think it is because the `Property ID :` is made null.

Why would it get the correct `Property ID :` for lets say 8 images then get a null for a while and then again get the correct `Property ID :`. and how can i fix this.

C# help welcome

Comment: Are you shure that sKey always contains str? --> `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey).Contains(str)`. Because if not ID = "".... And i would declare the varibles in the foreach.

Comment: I see what you are saying. thank you

Comment: Wired, I cant edit my comment. The second thing what I wanted to say was, I would create a new instance of the variables in the foreach. Btw. did you check if `skey` realy contains `str` everytime?

Comment: yes it does, and do you mean `For Each images As String In files
                For Each str As String In IDS
                    Dim id As String = ""
                    Dim photoID As String = ""
                    Dim position As String = ""`

Comment: No, just like that: `Dim blubb as String = "" Dim id As String = "" For Each images As String In files   For Each str As String In IDS 'ur stuff  Next Next`